# Paypal Integration holding money

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

I'm building a site that requires paypal integration. The way it works is I have buyers and sellers, the buyer requests the item, and pays for the item, but the seller needs to accept the money first.
So the money is held in limbo until the seller accepts it. Once accepted the money isn't transferred until the item has been received.

Can paypal do this? Also, can I do it with CakePHP?

Comment: Why, oh why would this belong on superuser? The question is valid, concerns the usage of a de-facto payment gateway and mentions a MVC framework being used. Its entirely programming related, non subjective and deserves an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this with a PayPal transfer.

A proper credit card processor like Authorize.net or PayPal's Payflow Pro service will let you place an authorisation hold on a credit card, and process the transaction at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just implement some kind of escrow service?

Comment: Sounds like that's exactly the service that he intends to make. However, it may violate one of PayPal's many user agreements; see https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=ua/Legal_Hub_full&locale.x=en_US for all the legalese.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP:

- [Medium difficulty Integration of PayPal into CakePHP](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/paypal-datasource)

In general:

- PayPal API can be found under "developement" on their main site
  But as the people above said, be careful with PayPal.
  Try to make some kind of contract with them, which ensures that your money won't get busted. (If you are willed to do high volume transfers via PayPal)

Tip: Always use bakery.cakephp.org, to find the best cake tutorials ;)